# How to use wildcard to be the variable and give it to a csh script

Tags: shell, csh

I'm not very sure how to describe my question, so I just use an example to explain what I want to do.

Example:

There are three files in a directory

aaa.txt, bbb.txt, ccc.log

I would use grep to check whether some keyword is in txt files, just like the following command.

```
grep keyword *.txt
```

I want to use a csh script to do the same thing. So I write a csh script.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/csh -f
grep 'keyword' $1
```

then I call it the same way.

```
./test.sh *.txt
```

It seems it just perform the grep to the first file in its list. 
How could I let test.sh go through to every file?

Comment: You might get some better answers over at [Unix and Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't know about csh but with /bin/sh you'd just do `grep 'keyword' "$@"`.

Comment: So many thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
grep 'keyword' $argv
```